# AdonisJS v5 project on IIS Node keeps restarting with each request

Tags: iis-7, iis-express, adonis.js

I am encountering an issue with an AdonisJS v5 project hosted on IIS Node using the HttpPlatformHandler module. Despite setting the application pool to "AlwaysRunning" and ensuring all relevant settings are properly configured, the server restarts with each request.

Upon checking the logs, there are no error messages or warnings that suggest the cause of these restarts. The AdonisJS project utilizes an IOC container to maintain the persistence of certain modules rather than recycling them.

Here is the relevant configuration from the web.config file:

```
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <add name="httppPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\RunningLog\node.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" arguments=".\build\server.js">
          <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
            <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="production" />
          </environmentVariables>
        </httpPlatform>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions from the community to help identify the underlying cause of this issue and suggest a possible solution. Thank you.

Comment: IIS Express or IIS?

Comment: You can try to debug the cause using [IIS Debug Diagnostics Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210), this tool will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.